# Slow loading/transparent menu bar during startup

Tags: startup, menu-bar

Sometimes when I startup my Mac, I notice that the menu bar doesn't load fully. It remains completely transparent and doesn't have a title (or any menu options) for the current application. It doesn't even have the Apple logo on the top left side.

Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Any idea what causes this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me too sometimes. A guaranteed solution: Restart the menu bar. Here's how:

Open Terminal (/Applications/Utilities). Type: `killall SystemUIServer`.
`killall` restarts the following process, and `SystemUIServer` is the process in charge of the menu bar.
 Once you press enter, the menu bar will disappear and reappear. It should be working fine.

Comment: It happens to me on a Mac Pro with 8 cores and 10GB RAM, but it usually goes away when you just switch to the finder back and forth another app, since the new app must refresh the bar.